# Is there a standard process to save Excel File Formatting/Settings into an Object?

Tags: vba, object, excel, formatting

It could be cumbersome at times to maitain Excel Workbook's formatting/settings when heavy backend, front end work loads are done. At times (even frequently) workbooks were crashed. But I can't recall what the code or process was to avoid this happening due to the formatting. What I am clear is that before any data retrieval, processing took place in the workbook,  I saved the Workbook's formatting/settings into an object. Once everything was completed, that object was called to restore. It was most probably one of the custom/user written classes.

That code was very handy when working with Workbooks to manage certain company standards/Logos/Colour Pallete/formatting/protection settings/code settings and so on.

So I just want to ask if anyone in the community have come across such process? I searched online and disappointing enough I am unable to find anything near - else I have really lost my wits on key-word search ;)

PS: This is not my home work or work. So please throw some light.

Comment: Sounds interesting but I haven't come accross it before. You might want to post this on Technet, or enquire at Dicks Blog.

Comment: @brettdj thanks for tips :) I am sort of thinking of writing my own class. But any good answers/relevant info to add some perspective would be great.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `PasteSpecial`...  Save the workbook to a temp location (or a hidden sheet) and then use a Copy & PasteSpecial to put just the formatting back later.

Comment: What about using .XLTX? You can setup a template workbook that is macro enabled. I've also used a database to hold parameters and spawn a handful of different sheets from the same button but they each got their own parameters from the database. I had 10 sheets with identical code, but the references on the worksheets were different. It made managing code much easier than doing the work in all 10 files.

Comment: @Bmo highest preference is given to a class, as it's easier to manage, transer just by creating objects :) Thanks for your idea though =)

Comment: It seems like you would be in it for a ton of formatting code with a class when you could call the template up and run with it. I'm not a huge fan of VBA's classes anyway (Or VBA for intense data manipulations and algorithms) It's not complied, but interpreted so some OO principles don't apply. Generally, creating a class is going to be your number 1 solution, but I don't know if creating a gigantic workflow of formatting is going to be the ideal, but maybe I'm not understanding the problem. Perhaps look at VSTO or an AddIn of some sort?

Comment: +1 I come across this problem 1-2 times.. where the excel file will crash itself very frequently.

Comment: @Bmo `1.` It depends on who's going to develop and maintain the code `2.` As per the restrictions similar to VB6 there's no `inheritance` - but through `interfaces` we can achieve `polymorphism` `3.` Since the Office model is based on classes, it's quite consistent to use classes in our code. `4.` I prefer to use Classes/Objects as it's much easier to migrate codes to C#, .Net, Java any OOP language :)

Comment: @Larry thanks mate :) long time no see..

Comment: I understand all that, but what scenario exists that you'll be porting excel formatting code to another language other than a VSTO application where you'll have to refactor it to death.

Comment: LOL I have fogotten to mention @Bmo the file suggestion that you had was great too. Specially for `colour styles`. I have been using that for sometime. However crashing is not happening due to the colour styling or simple formats, it's more less on the other aspects of the file, like settings.

Comment: Too bad VBA does not have something like `Reflection` and you could build setting dictionaries for worksheets by iterating over the properties of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about creating spreadsheets that conform to your branding standards, why don't you just create a template file:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/save-a-workbook-or-worksheet-as-a-template-HA010218874.aspx